# Delete field value highlighted by Ctrl + F

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have a very simple requirement. The screenshot shows a webpage with ediatble “UPC” fields. Currently we sometimes delete duplicate UPC’s by manually searching with Ctrl + F and deleting the highlighted field.

What I am looking for is the method to search and delete using Ctrl + f in UiPath. I know that Ctrl + F can be invoked using send hotkey option. But what I want to understand is how to do the remaining part of deleting the highlighted cell value post the Ctrl + F?

How can i do this with UiPath?

[image: screenshot of web page]

Let me modify my question here. My only requirement here is to understand how to find out a field highlighted by Ctrl + F. I dont want any other approaches to find duplicates etc.

Comment: How do you delete manually? Is there a delete button available for each row or check box select and then delete?

Comment: The UPC field is editable. We just select it and press Delete/BackSpace on the keyboard. Once all such duplicate UPC fields are cleared, we have an update button on the page which we click. My only blocking point is how to identify the field highlighted by the find operation and select it .

Comment: Your requirement is to have the cell's value changed. While you can send CTRL+F and the number to the browser, the next step would be to search for the highlighted cell. There are other - more direct - ways, such as the Find Element activity.

Answer (score 2):

The data is there in tabular form:

1. Scrape the data using Data Scraping wizard.
2. Iterate and find duplicates
3. Use UI Explorer - selector to find duplicates
4. Clear text in the duplicate cells
5. Click Update.

Comment: My only requirement here is to understand how to find out and select a field highlighted by Ctrl + F. I dont want any other approaches to find duplicates etc.

Answer (score 1):

Approach you are using can be converted in UiPath as:

1. Find Element Activity [Dynamic selector with value you are using in Ctrl+F in selector as variable]
2. Double Click [Same selector as above]
3. Send Hotkey 'del'